# How to draw the two parallel row diagrams in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, mathematics

I have drawn the folloing diagram:

[image]

Using the folloing tikz source code:

```
\[
            \begin{array}{ccccccc}
            A& 
            \subseteq&
            B&
            \subseteq&
            C&
             \subseteq &
             \cdots\\
            \parallel&&
            \parallel&& 
            \parallel
             \\
            AAA&
            \subseteq&
            BBB&
            \subseteq&
            CCC&
             \subseteq &
             \cdots
            \end{array}
            \]
```

**My question:**

- How to give more bigger $\subset$ symbol and $\parallel$ symbol and to adjusting the spaces in each rows ?
- How to write some text above the $subset$ symbol ? Can i use $\phantom{}$ ?

thanks

Comment: The  `relsize` package defines a `\mathlarger` command. For the second question, see the `stackengine` package.

Comment: @Bernard, Can you put the output, because it is not giving big `subset` symbol, \larger[] is just shifting the symbol

Comment: I can handle the 2nd uestion with the command `\overset`. What about the 1st question ? How to make larger  the `subset` symbol ?

Comment: use `\mathlarger{\subseteq}`– it should do it. Another possibility would be to change (locally) the font size.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution using `tikz-cd+scalerel` packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=small]
A \arrow[d, equal] &\scaleobj{4}{\subseteq} & B \arrow[d, equal] & \scaleobj{4}{\subseteq} & C \arrow[d, equal] & \cdots \\
AAA                              & \scaleobj{4}{\subseteq} & BBB                              & \scaleobj{4}{\subseteq} & CCC                              & \cdots
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a comment using `\overset` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=small]
A \arrow[d, equal] &
\overset{\textup{above}}{\scaleobj{4}{\subseteq} }&
B \arrow[d, equal] & \scaleobj{4}{\subseteq} & C \arrow[d, equal] & \cdots \\
AAA                              & \scaleobj{4}{\subseteq} & BBB                              & \scaleobj{4}{\subseteq} & CCC                              & \cdots
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But tikz-cd doesn't work in my old compiler.

Comment: @learner Why tikz-cd doesn't work in your old compiler?

Comment: I have repeaedly tried. Even I mentioned you regarding that in our old posts. I culd not update the compiler